# JS - a way to get value of variable at iteration instead of reference?

Tags: javascript

I ran into an interesting situation and I'm wondering what a very simple fix for this would be (in other words, how an experienced developer would handle this).

```
for(i = Math.min(storedAry.length,3)-1; i >=0; i--){
  var currentElementName = storedAry[i][1];
  var currentElementID = storedAry[i][0];
  var window_location = `BusTracking.html?id=${currentElementID}&name=${currentElementName}`;
  document.getElementById('recents').innerHTML+=`<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style='margin-bottom:20px;' onclick="window.location = window_location">${currentElementName}</button><br/>`;

}
```

I'm iterating through an an array and setting the button to redirect to the corresponding URL upon clicking. However, this above script will set the `window.location = window_location`, which is evaluated at the time the user clicks the button, so no matter what button is clicked, it will take the user to the page of what `window_location`'s value is when clicked (here, the last iteration of the loop).

I'm wondering how I can force evaluate this variable each time the for loop runs. A possible solution might be to access the array when `window_location` is accessed, but I feel like there should be a "PHP-like" way to do this.

Comment: Not when you are using an inline event handler. `window.location = window_location` is evaluated in global scope and there can only be one global `window_location` variable.

Comment: @FelixKling so there is no way to unwrap the `window_location` at each iteration? For example, Mathematica has the `Evaluate` function to do exactly this.

Comment: Well, one solution is to not evaluate `window_location` when the button is clicked but during the iteration. You could do exactly the same thing you do with the other variables: Embed their values into the template literal: `\`... onclick="window.location = '${window_location}'" ...\``. Now when any of the button is clicked `window.location = 'BusTracking.html?...'` is executed instead.

Comment: @FelixKling I didn't know that worked with the nested strings. Thanks so much!

Comment: Old school style `" ... window.location = '" + window_location + "' ... "`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply substitute the value of the variable into the template string.

```
document.getElementById('recents').innerHTML+=`<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style='margin-bottom:20px;' onclick="window.location = '${window_location}'">${currentElementName}</button><br/>`;
```

Comment: Thanks so much - didn't realize nested strings allowed this!

Comment: What did you think the difference is between `window_location` and `currentElementName` that allows you to substitute the latter?

Comment: my text editor wasn't doing syntax highlighting for the former which was nested in 3 strings (the outer string, the onclick string, and the innermost string), so I assumed that because it was nested, it wouldn't evaluate.